# Is there an hg equivalent to git-mv?

Tags: mercurial

I have a file foo.py with some history.  I want to rename it bar.py but see the history with "hg log".

I tried "hg rename".  It does not seem to maintain the history.

FYI. I only browsed the man page.

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for the answer.

As an addendum, if foo.py is 500 KB, will a rename increase the size of the repository by at least 500 KB?  Is there any way where it can not do this and simply store a name mapping?

Comment: Niall has your answer -- rename (aliased to mv) is the correct command to use, you just have to ask log to follow renames.  And yes, a full second copy of the file is created.  There's some work being done on cheap renames, but for now you're storing two.

Comment: If the file is highly compressible (like source code tends to be), the copy in the repository (i.e. underneath the .hg directory) will be a lot smaller than 500kB.

Comment: @Niall an excellent point.  You get a new copy in the repo that doesn't diff/delta against older revisions, but it's still compressed.

Comment: @ Niall.  Your comment got me curious. I checked out a fresh gnu octave and did du: (Values in kilobyte)

5332 octave/scripts
60744 octave/.hg
86664 octave

Performed a Rename of octave/scripts to octave/scripts2.  

5332 octave/scripts2
64612 octave/.hg
90532 octave    it seems that the store is compressed by a ratio of about 3880/5332.  Do you think this compression ratio has to do with how many separate files you have vs how long each individual file is?

Comment: each file gets compressed and stored individually.  You'd get better results with fewer bigger files. A quick informal test on some source code: a 25MB file compressed to about 1.2MB under .hg, vs. 322 files totaling 3.2MB compressed to about 600kB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hg log --follow`.  From `hg help log`:

> -f --follow               follow changeset history, or file history across copies and renames

Comment: This is something that is not intuitive with mercurial as you have to ask it to follow the renames/moves for the history display. It will automatically understand the move when merging branches but not for history.